# I keep getting logged out in Firefox

Tags: admin, wp-admin, login, logout

For some reason, tonight  when I have gone to work on my Wordpress installation I firstly found myself logged out, even though there was a few cookies left in Firefox relating to the website and when I looked on the Simple:Press forum it had remembered my user name but knew I wasn't logged in. Nevertheless, I logged in again and it worked perfectly... until I navigate to a different page when it seems as though I never logged in; furthermore if I try to go directly to the Admin Dashboard from the page when it says I am logged in, it asks me to login again and the URL says `reauth=1` at the end.

Strangely, this only occurs in Mozila  Firefox and it works perfectly on the same computer using Internet Explorer! Also, I can recall me doing anything to the installation yesterday for it to invoke this kind of behaviour today!

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen occasionally on both Firefox and Safari when cookies don't match.  Sometimes, WordPress will store an auth cookie and, for some reason, won't read data back out of it.  This leaves you in a weird place of being semi-logged-in.

If you flush your cookies for the site, it should rectify the problem.  Either delete the cookies manually via Firebug or tell FireFox to delete all cookies (either globally or just for the site), then log back in.

Comment: How strange. I've just deleted all of my cookies using Firefox, restarted the browser and tried to log in and so far everything appears to be fine and back to normal. Thank you for your answer! In a way I'm glad the problem is nothing to do with my installation, but now I'm slightly worried that the bug might put anybody who isn't  aware of it off our website. Though, I suppose that could happen on any website... Just wondering and it doesn't really matter but do you know why this doesn't happen in IE or even does happen in Firefox and Safari?

Comment: It can actually happen in any browser, but I've only ever seen the issue in FF and Safari on live sites. When all else fails, flush cached information :)

Answer (score 1):

I've just discovered today after a reading an article (I can't remember where) and the same thing happening today, that it doesn't seem to be cookie related as such; rather to do with the site and wordpress address!

It appears that because the `WordPress Address` pointed to "http://**www.** diabetesuknelfsg.org.uk" rather than just "http://diabetesuknelfsg.org.uk" there was a conflict - one that obviously some web browsers are programmed to ignore. As soon as I removed the `www.` my problems went away. Lets hope this is a more permanent fix as well!

Help that helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

Yet another reason this could be is that the "Edit" button in the front end of a post, is using a cdn's domain (caching the links but also switching the domains, causing cookie confusion and thus logging you out) rather than your own site. Some hosting providers offer link caching that intercept these admin links as well.  You can test it by copying the latter part of the link and seeing if that does not log you out.

`http://jojud265nia2bj9.some-cdn-provider.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=16144&action=edit`

Try copying the latter part of the link (without the host) and using your actual site and see if you still get logged out

`http://www.examplesite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=16144&action=edit`

If you didn't get logged out, maybe the cdn domain switching is the problem.